# Azure storage connection to Datalake G2 in SSIS using Access Key

Tags: ssis, azure-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2, ssis-connection-manager

Test connection Connection manger in  SSIS to the azure storage using access key succeeded.
While copying data using Flexible file task in SSIS throwing an error "[Flexible File Task] Error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common, Version=11.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
The Folder paths and filenames everything seems correct.
What would be reason?

> Azure.Storage.Common nuget package getting removed as soon as I close script task to run the package and throws same error

Comment: That error means that some part of the library was not installed correctly. Try a reinstall or repair

Answer (score 2):

This is a spurious error message. It is a security error

Go to your storage account, under Settings, Configuration, change Minimum TLS version from 1.2 to 1.0.

Or if you want to keep the 1.2 channel, you will need to modify the registry on the computers that may run the SSIS package

> To use TLS 1.2, add a REG_DWORD value named SchUseStrongCrypto with data 1 under the following two registry keys. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319

https://billfellows.blogspot.com/2022/01/ssis-azure-feature-pack-and-flexible.html

Furthermore, based on your comment referencing nuget. Nuget and SSIS Script Tasks and Components do not mix. The Developer experience of crafting a script knows how to use the nuget package manager to acquire the assemblies. However, when you close the script/component editor, those bits are not serialized with the project. When the package executes, there is no part of the run-time engine that identifies this assembly is from a nuget source and therefore, we need to download those bits. Instead, it fails when it cannot find the reference.

It still seems weird that a script task/component is throwing an exception about the azure bits as the Flexible File Task is not a script. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/flexible-file-task?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Azure.Storage.Common nuget package getting removed as soon as I close script task to run the package and throws same error,Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common, Version=11.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Comment: Ohhhh, you hadn't specified nuget was involved, sec as I update

Comment: @Equator did you manage to get this working? I get the exact same error in my SSIS package when trying to access Azure storage Lake Gen2. If you so please help me. I have update the registry as mentioned in billinkc 's post with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the correct Azure Feature Pack for Integration Services (SSIS) targeting the SQL server resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

i had exact same issue yesterday; what i did is downloaded from nuget the missing library in the nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common/11.1.3
once downloaded i renamed it to extension .zip and then extracted the ddl file from it;
once its extracted i used the gacutil.exe to actually install the ddl
after that when i ran the ssis package again i received also an error, but a different one, which was specifying in more details what the real problem was (in my case: invalid character in the path: i changed the path from the full path to just the container name ); hope this helps anyone with the same error in the future